# ActivePivot Indexer data removal

Tags: activepivot

Anyone encountered this use case?

When we removed data from the indexer using the objectkey, `AP` successfully returned that all data was removed.

We tried to confirm by executing the same removal criteria and AP returns 0 count. But when we try to query via MDX, the Cube returns a record. Then tried again to removed with same criteria CUBE return 0 count.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We do not have a clear understanding of what you tried, could you  provide a sample code, its actual output and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

you're saying 
But when we try to query via MDX, the Cube returns a record
are you querying the contributors.COUNT ?

also you can simplify and share your removal code 
Regards,

Comment: The count shows partial result. How We did the removal is, we query the indexer based on certain condition, then executing the condition using schema.getIndexer.execute, then I implemented  IProcedure<IProjection>. then I created a callback variable to get the results which is the projectionKey/s popolated in the execute method, Then I used this returned projectionkeys as my key to remove in the schema.. One thing  I noticed when you return false on the execute method of the IProcedure this case happened, so I just force it to always return TRUE.

Comment: I was able to found a workaround by compacting/compressing the indexer and it seems the behaviour was back as expected

Comment: what do you mean exactly by : compacting/compressing the indexer ?